# List of Dictionary Arrays

Tags: vb.net, list, dictionary, multidimensional-array, webmethod

Hit a wall, and can't find much in docs.

I have two dictionaries, and I'd like to put them in a list.

```
Dim listOfDictionaries As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))
```

is not working.

Am I correct in assuming that once I get this dimmed, I can .add the conventional way?

**Details (EDIT)**

When trying to listOfDictionaries.Add(dictionaryIWantToAdd), I get "value of type '1-dimensional array system.collection.generic.dictionary(of string, string)' cannot be converted to 'system.collection.generic.dictionary(of string, string)'

**Solution**

Helps to put the () on the end an array.   :P

Comment: Why isn't it working? What error are you getting?

Comment: `is not working` -- please be more specific here.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Note that as it stands his title should be empty :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conventional way is:

```
Dim both = New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))()
both.Add(Dictionary1)
both.Add(Dictionary2)
```

Comment: Your two samples do different things: In the first sample you create a list with key-value pairs from both dictionaries. In the second sample you create a list containing the two dictionaries directly.

Comment: @Meta-Knight: I should end my day if i overlook such things ;)

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all.  You are trying to add an array of dictionaries to the list, but the add method only takes a single dictionary, not an array of them.  Either fix it so you are only passing in a single dictionary:

```
Dim myDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, String)
' ...
listOfDictionaries.Add(myDictionary)
```

Or use the `AddRange` method to add all the dictionaries in the array at once:

```
Dim myArrayOfDictionaries() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
' ...
listOfDictionaries.AddRange(myArrayOfDictionaries)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to favour single-line solutions when it's something straightforward like this, making use of the [`From`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384802.aspx) keyword.

```
Dim listOfDictionaries = New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)) From { dictionary1, dictionary2 }
```